# LINE chat from with contact

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open [LINE](https://line.me/en/) chat with specific contact (phone number)

I see they have a [developer site](https://developers.line.biz/en/) but i can't seem to find a simple solution

in Whatsapp it was quite simple using the next code

```
void whatsapp(String phone) {

    phone = phone.replace( "+","" );

    try{
        Intent sendIntent =new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,""); 
        sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", phone +"@s.whatsapp.net");
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mActivity.startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity,"Error/n"+ e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

ps: please make LINE tag, i can't see to find it although Whatsapp and wechat available

Comment: All the documented Url schemes are [here](https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/line-login/using-line-url-scheme/) see if you find the solution .

Comment: you cant use intent to send number to line some apps like Skype and WhatsApp you can. but for the line, I don't think so

Comment: line://nv/chat opens the chats page but i can't seem to find a way to open with phone number. It is very strange, they have so many developer options....